# How to validate a specific number of text input fields for an entry?

Tags: javascript, validation

`number_people_household` is a drop down that decides how many input text fields are visible in the next question. My problem arises when I want to validate that specific number of visible fields. For example if there are 3 fields I want to validate the three visible ones for text. If one or more are empty `alert("mistake")`. If all visible fields are filled carry out the `loadNew()` function.

```
function checkSeveralFilled() {

    var e = document.getElementById("number_people_household");
    var amount = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i in inp; i < amount;){
        if(inp[i].type == "text"){
            if(inp[i].value != ""){
                loadNew();
            }
            else {
                alert("missing value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Added some HTML. For some reason my function is not recognising any input types equaling "text" I assume.

```
<div class="question">
<div class="white_box">
    List the ages of people in your household?
</div>
<div class="answer">
    <div class="rule" id="rules">
        Only Numbers Allowed, eg 14, 15, 44, 45
    </div>

    <input id="person1" class="person1" type="text" placeholder="Person 1" onkeyup="checkInputs(this)"/>
    <input id="person2" class="person1" type="text" placeholder="Person 2" onkeyup="checkInputs(this)"/>
    <input id="person3" class="person1" type="text" placeholder="Person 3" onkeyup="checkInputs(this)"/>
    <input id="person4" class="person1" type="text" placeholder="Person 4" onkeyup="checkInputs(this)"/>
    <input id="person5" class="person1" type="text" placeholder="Person 5" onkeyup="checkInputs(this)"/>
    <input id="person6" class="person1" type="text" placeholder="Person 6" onkeyup="checkInputs(this)"/>
    <input id="person7" class="person1" type="text" placeholder="Person 7" onkeyup="checkInputs(this)"/>
    <input id="person8" class="person1" type="text" placeholder="Person 8" onkeyup="checkInputs(this)"/>
    <input id="person9" class="person1" type="text" placeholder="Person 9" onkeyup="checkInputs(this)"/>
    <input id="person10" class="person1" type="text" placeholder="Person 10" onkeyup="checkInputs(this)"/>
</div>
</div>

function checkSeveralFilled() {
debugger;
var a = document.getElementById("number_people_household");
var amount1 = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;

var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var callFunc = true;

for (var i = 0; i < amount1; i++) {
    if(inp[i].type == "text"){
    alert("found");
        if(inp[i].value == ""){
            alert("missing value");
            inp[i].focus();
            callFunc = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (callFunc)
{
    alert("call loadNew()");
}
}
```

Comment: Let me get this right... you have e.g. 5 input fields and a selectbox to choose how many should be displayed? How about do delete hidden boxes before you validate them or only create an amout of fields depending on the selectbox? This way your validation has only to deal with visible and used fields.

Comment: The user needs to have a option to back and change their answer to the selectbox. If a user selects 4 for example and then goes back and selects 5. Will five fields appear or will only four appear because field5 was deleted on the first attempt?

Comment: Than you should generate input fields after the change in the selectbox.